# Replacing NULL values in LEFT JOIN with MAX function

Tags: sql-server

I have created a query that join two tables and returns a date of the last log in of a particular user. If a user logged in multiple times, the query returns the most recent date:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    USERID varchar(255),
    NAME varchar(255)
)
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    USERID varchar(255),
    LOGIN_TIME varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO Table1(USERID, NAME)
VALUES ('XYZ_1234', 'RAMBO'),
       ('XYZ_1235', 'ARNOLD'),
       ('XYZ_1236', 'BRUCE')
INSERT INTO Table2(USERID,LOGIN_TIME)
VALUES ('1234','17.07.17'),
       ('1234','20.07.17'),
       ('1235', '27.08.17')

SELECT T1.NAME, MAX (T2.LOGIN_TIME)
CASE WHEN T2.LOGIN_TIME IS NULL THEN 5 ELSE T2.LOGIN_TIME
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.USERID='XYZ_' + T2.USERID
GROUP BY T1.NAME
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c119d/2

What I'm struggling with is to replace "null" values that are returned every time when a user exist in table1 and does not exist in table2.
For that I was trying to write a "CASE" function (line 2 in the link above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL(MAX(T2.LOGIN_TIME), 'Default Value')` to replace the `NULL`.

But first you should consider that `LOGIN_TIME varchar(255)` with values such as `17.07.17` that holds dates should be `DATE` data type. Always use `DATE` or `DATETIME` when using dates, as varchars become troublesome when comparing or ordering (and even understanding them depending on culture info).

For example, the `MAX()` on a varchar value of `17.07.18` against `27.08.17` will return `27.08.17` because `27` is higher as literal than `17`, but the year of the latter (2018) is higher than the former, thus returning an incorrect result. This won't happen if the column is `DATE` or `DATETIME` type.

This is the fixed SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    USERID varchar(255),
    NAME varchar(255)
)
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    USERID varchar(255),
    LOGIN_TIME DATE -- It's date here!
)
INSERT INTO Table1(USERID, NAME)
VALUES ('XYZ_1234', 'RAMBO'),
       ('XYZ_1235', 'ARNOLD'),
       ('XYZ_1236', 'BRUCE')
INSERT INTO Table2(USERID,LOGIN_TIME)
VALUES ('1234','2017-07-17'),
       ('1234','2017-07-20'),
       ('1235', '2017-08-27') -- ISO format

SELECT 
    T1.NAME, 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), MAX(T2.LOGIN_TIME)), '5')
FROM 
    Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.USERID ='XYZ_' + T2.USERID
GROUP BY 
    T1.NAME
```

If you are using a default value of a literal `'5'` then you have no other choice than converting the max login time to varchar so both types are compatible.

Maybe you wanted to display a particular date instead?

Answer (score 1):

I used a common table expression to do the group by and then referenced that CTE with the `CASE` expression.  Your `CASE` expression didn't really make sense to me as far as the replacement value of '5', but that's what I used.

```
WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT T1.NAME
        ,MAX(T2.LOGIN_TIME) AS LOGIN_TIME
    FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
        ON T1.USERID = 'XYZ_' + T2.USERID
    GROUP BY T1.NAME
    )
SELECT NAME
    ,CASE 
        WHEN LOGIN_TIME IS NULL
            THEN '5'
        ELSE LOGIN_TIME
        END AS LOGIN_TIME
FROM _cte
```

---

```
| NAME   | LOGIN_TIME |
|--------|------------|
| ARNOLD | 27.08.17   |
| BRUCE  | 5          |
| RAMBO  | 20.07.17   |
```